# Ascending Numbers in Macro Definition

Tags: macros, scheme, racket

I frequently use Racket's pattern-matching construct `match`, and I thought a way to help myself with debugging programs using `match`, and to learn how Racket/Scheme macros work, would be to create a macro that includes information like which pattern was matched.

In other words, I'm looking to create a macro that, given this:

```
(match/debug 'two
  ['one 1]
  ['two 2])
```

Outputs something like this:

```
Case 2 <-- Printed
2      <-- Returned value
```

The main obstacle so far has been trying to get the numbers signifying the resolved case to show up correctly.

My target was to try to write something that would expand like this:

```
(match 'two
  ['one (displayln "Case 1") 1]
  ['two (displayln "Case 2") 2])
```

But I haven't been able to figure out any way to generate those "Case #" strings.

Here is my attempted macro definition:

```
(define-syntax-rule (match/debug id [pattern value] ...)
  (let ([index 0])
    (match id
      [(begin
         (set! index (add1 index))
         pattern)
       (printf "Case ~a\n" index)
       value] ...)))
```

It appears as though the syntax of `match` won't let me do something like this, but this was the only way I could think of.  I'm only really used to Common Lisp's style of macros.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution.

The helper function `clauses->numbers` returns a list of the numbers from 0 to the one less than the number of clauses. This is then used to give each clause its own number. Note that this solution counts from 0 (and not 1 as in your examples).

```
#lang racket
(require (for-syntax syntax/parse))

(begin-for-syntax
  (require racket/list) ; import range
  (define (clauses->numbers stx)
    (range (length (syntax->list stx)))))

(define-syntax (match/debug stx)
  (syntax-parse stx
    [(_match/debug id [pattern value] ...)
     (with-syntax ([(n ...) (clauses->numbers #'([pattern value] ...))])
       (syntax/loc stx
         (match id
           [pattern (begin (displayln (~a "Case: " n)) value)]
           ...)))]))

(match/debug 'one
  ['one 1]
  ['two 2])

(match/debug 'two
  ['one 1]
  ['two 2])
```

The output:

```
Case: 0
1
Case: 1
2
```

Comment: Funnily enough...I actually ended up using the quoted pattern, it gave me sufficient info.  But thanks for the quick and thorough response!